# How to save in SQLitedatabase permanently

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have created a SQLitedatabase and want to store data. But the data is deleted on each start of the app again, because the "create table" methods are implemented in in the OnCreate-Method of the database.

1. How can i prevent that the OnCreate Method is called on each start of the app.
2. Where does the creation of the database object fits best?

OnCreate of the database:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //if (!dbNinjaExists(db)) {
        createTables(db);
        initNinjas(db);
    //}
}
```

Th initNinjas method contains some Insert SQLs which create the sample data. I already tried to make an if-decision in the constructor to ask whether there is already a database but this doesnt work.

```
private boolean dbNinjaExists(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if(data.equals(null)){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

The constructor of the MasterActivity creates the database object and starts with beginning of the app. As following:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);}
```

The DatabaseHelper Constructor:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context,TABLE_NAME,null,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my **SQLiteAdapter** (DBHelper)Class:

Using this this db will be created only once. You can call this from any method and activity. Make changes according to your requirement.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class SQLiteAdapter {

private static final String DB_NAME = "DATABASE";
private static final String KEY_TABLE = "KEY_TABLE";

private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEYWORD = "Keyword";
private static final String COUNT = "COUNT";
private static final String CONTACT_NAMES = "CONTACT_NAMES";
private static final String CONTACT_NUMBERS = "CONTACT_NUMBERS";


//create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
        "create table " + KEY_TABLE + " ("
                + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + KEYWORD + " text, "
                + CONTACT_NAMES + " text, "
                + CONTACT_NUMBERS + " text, "
                + COUNT + " integer);";

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

private Context context;

SQLiteAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

private void openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();

}

private void openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

}

private void close() {
    sqLiteHelper.close();
}

boolean insert(SQLiteAdapter sqLiteAdapter, String keyword, String contact_names, String contact_numbers, int count) {

    sqLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(KEYWORD, keyword);
    contentValues.put(CONTACT_NAMES, contact_names);
    contentValues.put(CONTACT_NUMBERS, contact_numbers);
    contentValues.put(COUNT, count);
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(KEY_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    sqLiteAdapter.close();
    return true;
}

void deleteRow(SQLiteAdapter sqLiteAdapter, String id) {

    sqLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("delete from " + KEY_TABLE + " where _id='" + id + "'");
    sqLiteAdapter.close();


}

ArrayList<RecordModel> getAllRecords(SQLiteAdapter sqLiteAdapter) {

    sqLiteAdapter.openToRead();
    ArrayList<RecordModel> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEYWORD, CONTACT_NAMES, CONTACT_NUMBERS, COUNT};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(KEY_TABLE, columns,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            RecordModel recordModel = new RecordModel();
            recordModel.setCount(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COUNT)));
            recordModel.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            recordModel.setKeyword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEYWORD)));
            recordModel.setContactNames(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_NAMES)));
            recordModel.setContactNumbers(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_NUMBERS)));
            listItems.add(recordModel);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();

    sqLiteAdapter.close();

    return listItems;
}


public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                 CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i think it is the same as my db, because the execSQL is called in the OnCreate Method of the SQLiteOpenHelper. By creating an object of the db(SQLiteOpenHelper) it will always be executed and overwrites existing tables.

Comment: It doesn't overwrite as it checks the version. If version is same you get the same data. Please check if your helper is extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: See the constructor

Comment: Ive added my default constructor above. I want to try your constructor now, but the CursorFactory object is unknown. Which Library is implementing CursorFactory?

Comment: Check the import statements

Comment: Ok ive added the constructor in DatabaseHelper. But which parameters do i have to pass when creating the DatabaseHelper? I recently used dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this); called from MasterActivty, but now i have to pass three paramters more. Should i null these paramters? What are they for?

Comment: No my friend. There are 2 constructors. You only have to pass context.

Comment: There are 2 classes in this. Make sure you call the main class with context.

Comment: So it would be SQLiteAdapter sqa = new SQLiteAdapter(this) in my case

Comment: The other class is used within the main class. That's why I told you to use my code. It would be easier for you to understand then

Comment: ive tried to edit constructor now but data isnt stored again. My database is very big and has a lot of methods already so i wanted to avoid to make such a big improvement. But the small improvement failed too, so i now will try it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please submit your RecordModel class?

Answer (score 0):

If this:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context,TABLE_NAME,null,1);
}
```

is your constructor, 
it creates a database with name the value of `TABLE_NAME` which is I suppose the name of the table you want to create.  
So change `TABLE_NAME` with the database name.